# Why is there mold on the ceiling of my second floor balcony?

Tags: mold, siding

I have owned a new build house since August of last year. There is a balcony on the second floor and the ceiling of it is below my third floor. The side of the house has HardyPlank siding. Since last year I have noticed something dark on the ceiling which looks like mold or mildew. I also live in hot and humid Houston. I noticed that my neighbors do not have this, although I do not know if they just clean it. Is this normal or do I have a problem of moisture getting between the floor of the third story and the balcony ceiling? I’ve attached a picture of what is looks like. Thanks!

[image: Ceiling picture]

Comment: Is that ceiling drywall? That wasn't ever painted?

Comment: That’s what I am wondering. I’m not sure how to tell. Either it’s the wrong paint or moisture is getting in between the floors.

Comment: it's not moisture getting into the ceiling/floor, it's cold getting in, which causes outside moisture via your high dewpoint in houston. insulate better and the mold will stop growing.